# Как получить фрагмент html кода?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, lxml

```
xxp= '//*[contains(@class, "iongIs")]//*[preceding::*[contains(text(), "Кэшбэк")]]'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser') # получаем страницу
dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))
content = dom.xpath(xxp) # сужаемся до нужного фрагмента, желательно получить html фрагмент
```

... тут что то должно быть

```
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser') # content это фрагмент нужного кода
table = soup2.find_all('table')
```

Тоесть я хочу с помощью xpath получить нужный фрагмент и дальше его использовать в BeautifulSoup. Как это сделать ?

Comment: Что мешает сделать просто `content[0].find_all('table')` ? Что-то я не понял сути проблемы

Comment: @andreymal - у content нет метода find_all

Comment: Опечатка, метод `findall` вполне себе существует, только что проверил

Comment: @andreymal - у меня большая часть кода сделана под объект BeautifulSoup, а у него find_all. А content с findall это другой объект ...

Comment: Да и вообще, если вам прям позарез нужен xpath, то наверное лучше остановиться на использовании lxml без всяких BeautifulSoup, Иначе постоянные конвертирования туда-сюда выглядят как бесполезная трата электричества

Comment: Ну а если вам прям позарез нужен BeautifulSoup, то `lxml.html.tostring(content[0], encoding="unicode")` выдаст html-код, который можно запихнуть в него

Comment: @andreymal - было бы неплохо если бы весь content переводил сразу, без использвания цикла